# How to tranform simple json to nested json in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, nested, parent-child, parent

I have a API which return simple json. Which need to be converted into nested JSON array in a parent/child relation based on "ParentId" in each node.Below is the sample JSON array which I get from API..Can enyone post any example of function in JavaScript  to achieve this?

I'm trying to make kendo TreeList view in react.

I want this:

```
   const employees = [
  {  
    "id" :1,
    "IdChild": 23890952,
    "ParentId": null
  },
  {
      "id" :2,
      "IdChild": 23890953,
      "ParentId": 23890952

},
{
   "id":3,
   "IdChild": 23890954,
    "ParentId": 23890953

 }
      
    
];
```

transform to this:

```
const employees = [
  {  
    "id" :1,
    "IdChild": 23890952,
    "ParentId": null,
   
    "employees":[{
      "id" :2,
        "IdChild": 23890953,
        "ParentId": 23890952,
        
        "employees":[{
            "id":3,
            "IdChild": 23890954,
            "ParentId": 23890953

        }]
      
    }]
  },

];
```

export default employees;

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution.

```
const result = employees.reduceRight(
    (all, item) => ({ ["employees"]: [{ ...item, ...all }] }),
    {}
);
```

Explanation:

- We are using reduceRight. I will start reading the array from the last index.
- In the second step, we are creating an object and adding it back to the second last object, and so on.

We can also make id as a key of object

```
const result = employees.reduceRight(
    (all, item) => ({ [item.id]: [{ ...item, ...all }] }),
    {}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Takes in an array of objects with parent and child keys 
// and returns an array with one nested object
function objectify(objs){
    // loop through all the elements to create an empty 
    // array corresponding to the key "employees"
    objs.forEach(obj => obj["employees"] = []);
    retVal = []
    // Assumes the first element is always the root/parent
    const root = objs.shift()
    retVal.push(root)
    objs.forEach(obj => insert(root, obj));
    return retVal

    // Helper function to insert every object to the correct parent
    function insert(parent, curr){
        if(parent.IdChild === curr.ParentId) {parent["employees"].push(curr); return}
        parent["employees"].forEach((child)=>insert(child, curr))
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I tried those solutions but they dont work for me if i have response like this:

```
 const employees =[
    {
       
        "IdChild": 23982608,
        "ParentId": null,
        "id" :1
    },
    {
       
        "IdChild": 23982609,
        "ParentId": 23982608,
         "id" :2
    },
    {
        
        "IdChild": 23982610,
        "ParentId": 23982608,
         "id" :3
    },
    {
      
        "IdChild": 23982611,
        "ParentId": 23982608,
         "id" :4
    },
    {
      
        "IdChild": 23982978,
        "ParentId": 23982611,
         "id" :5
    },
    {
       
        "IdChild": 23982979,
        "ParentId": 23982978,
         "id" :6
    },
   ]
```

this is how i want response to look like:

```
 const employees =[
    

    {
       
        "IdChild": 23982608,
        "ParentId": null,
        "id" :1,
        "employees":[
           {
       
            "IdChild": 23982609,
            "ParentId": 23982608,
            "id" :2
          },
          {
        
            "IdChild": 23982610,
            "ParentId": 23982608,
            "id" :3
          },
          {
      
            "IdChild": 23982611,
            "ParentId": 23982608,
            "id" :4,
            "employees":
                        [
                          {
                          "IdChild": 23982978,
                          "ParentId": 23982611,
                          "id" :5,
            
                          "employees": [
                                        {
         
                                          "IdChild": 23982979,
                                          "ParentId": 23982978,
                                          "id" :6
         
                                         }
                                        ]
         
                         }]
         
         
          }
        ]
    }
   ];
```